# How can I fix the problem of Visual Studio Code Intellisense not working for JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I'm currently in the middle of developing a website and I suddenly noticed that my VS code IntelliSense completely stop working.  It does not show any suggestions, auto import, emmet, hover details, etc. for JavaScript and TypeScript files. It works fine for other languages like Python and C#. Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem:

> *My VS Code*
> [image: My VS code]

> *VS code on the web*
> [image: VS code on the web]

It also extended to Typescript as well. It like it is completely dead. I noticed that when I hover to see the typescript version on the bottom right corner, it doesn't show the version like on the web or other computer.

> *My VS Code*
> [image: My VS code]

> *VS code on the web*
> [image: VS code on the web]

I have tried reinstalling VS Code, disabling all extensions, deleting the workspace cache, and updating the settings.json file, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?